# How can open date toggle in Angular npm mydatepicker?

Tags: angular, datepicker

I am using Angular npm mydatepicker(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker). I want to open date toggle If I click input of datepicker. It only opens and closes When Datepicker button is clicked.

[image]

This is my code:

```
<my-date-picker name="mydate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions"
        (dateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)" [placeholder]="'Дата оплаты'"> 
</my-date-picker>
```

Can Anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: can you show `myDatePickerOptions` ?

Comment: Yeah, But I could not find this option which I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refering to [the doc](https://github.com/kekeh/mydatepicker), there is an option for this:

> name: openSelectorOnInputClick
>   default: false
>   type: boolean
>   description: Open selector when the input field is clicked. Can be
>   used if inline = false and editableDateField = false.

Comment: It works. Thanks. I have done it but I did not add editableDateField:(
`public myDatePickerOptions: IMyDpOptions = {
    openSelectorOnInputClick: true,
    editableDateField: false
  };`
It is solution:)